# Making a groupby query faster

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is my data from my table:

[image]

I mean i have exactly one million rows so it is just a snippet.
**I would like to make this query faster:**[image]

Which basically groups the values by time (ev represents year honap represents month and so on.). It has one problem that it takes a lot of time. I tried to apply indexes as you can see here:

[image]

but it does absolutely nothing.
Here is my index:
[image]

I have tried also to put the perc (which represents minute) due to cardinality but mysql doesnt want to use that. Could you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Your current query is technically invalid, and I don't even know why you are aggregating.  Try adding sample input and output data.

Comment: It is not possible to get an average of all the rows without reading all the rows (which is what's happening currently). The only way to speed it up is to have another table with the final result in it, and refresh it periodically or with a trigger.

Comment: Tim Bigeleisen -> i would like to make a graph out of these values in python (X: time, Y: value). The reason why im storing the datas in mysql because i dont want to store all the data in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the data realistic?  If so, why run the query -- it essentially delivers exactly what was in the table.

If, on the other hand, you had *several* rows per minute, then the `GROUP BY` makes sense.

The index you have is not worth using.  However, the Optimizer seemed to like it.  That's a bug.

In that case, I would simply this:

```
SELECT AVG(konyha1) AS 'avg',
       LEFT(time, 16) AS 'time'
    FROM onemilliondata
    GROUP BY LEFT(time, 16)
```

A `DATE` or `TIME` or `DATETIME` can be treated as such a datatype *or* as a `VARCHAR`.  I'm asking for it to be a string.

Even in this case, no index is useful.  However, this would make it a little faster:

```
PRIMARY KEY(time)
```

and the table would have only 2 columns:  time, konyha1.

It is *rarely* beneficial to break a date and/or time into components and put them into columns.

A million points will probably choke a graphing program.  And the screen -- which has a resolution of only a few thousand.

Perhaps you should group by hour?  And use `LEFT(time, 13)`?  Performance would probably be slightly faster -- but only because less data is being sent to the client.

If you are collecting this data "forever", consider building and maintaining a "summary table" of the averages for each unit of time.  Then the incremental effort is, say, aggregating yesterday's data each morning.

You might find `MIN(konyha1)` and `MAX(konyha1)` interesting to keep on an hourly or daily basis.  Note that daily or weekly aggregates can be derived from hourly values.